# How to view the array of exif tag through this metadata extractor library?

Tags: java, android, metadata, exif, metadata-extractor

Couldnt locate the part to print out the entire array of the method getTagName() as it is in the form of tag and not a string.

https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

```
 try {
    InputStream is = new URL("http://www.dbituser1.dbitmobileappchallenge.com/uploadimage1/uploads/sample_0%20-%20Copy.jpg").openStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis);

    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
        for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
            //Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "" + tag.getTagName() +": " + tag.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (tag.getTagName().contains("ISO")) {
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                text.setText("ISO: " + tag.getDescription());
            }

            if (tag.getTagName().contains("Exposure")) {
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "This is the Date: " + tag.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //text.setText("Exposure: " + tag.getDescription());
            }
        }
    }
} catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need two values, don't iterate all of them. Instead, pull out the specific directory you're looking for, then the tag directly.

From your code, it looks like you need `ExifSubIfdDirectory`.

```
ExifSubIFDDirectory subIfd = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);

if (subIfd != null) {
    // NOTE these values could be null if they aren't present in the image's metadata
    Integer iso = subIfd.getInteger(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_ISO_EQUIVALENT);
    Double exposureTime = subIfd.getDoubleObject(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME);
}
```